# how to correctly generate an nested array in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue application where I am right now getting this kind of an json object:

```json
    [
       {
          "meetingName":"ewq",
          "meetingUrl":"",
          "meetingPw":"",
          "date":"2021-05-30",
          "times":[
             {
                "startTime":"15:30",
                "endTime":"16:30"
             },
             {
                "startTime":"17:30",
                "endTime":"18:30"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "meetingName":"ewq",
          "meetingUrl":"",
          "meetingPw":"",
          "date":"2021-05-31",
          "times":[
             {
                "startTime":"15:30",
                "endTime":"16:30"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

But I am aiming for something like this:

```json
      {
      "meetingName":"Test",
      "meetingPw":"test22",
      "meetingUrl":"localhost",
      "meetingTimes":[
         {
            "date":"15.12.2020",
            "times":[{
               "startTime":"15:00",
               "endTime":"16:00"
            }]
         },
         {
            "date":"25.12.2020",
            "times":[
               {
                  "startTime":"17:00",
                  "endTime":"18:00"
               },
               {
                  "startTime":"19:00",
                  "endTime":"2:00"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

But I just cant change it to get like this in my code, could someone look at my code and tell me where my mistake is?

```js
    <script>
    import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";
    
    export default {
      name: "GenerateMeetingSettings",
    
      data: () => ({
        selectedTime: [],
        dates: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
        datesFinal: [],
        meetingSettingUrl: "",
        meetingPW: "",
        generatedLink: false,
        meetingName: "",
        dialog: false,
        menu: false,
        modal: false,
        menu2: false,
        menu3: false
      }),
    
      methods:{
    
        addTimeFields(){
    
          this.selectedTime.push({
            startTime:"",
            endTime: "",
          })
        },
        saveDateAndTIme(e) {
          this.datesFinal.push({
            meetingName: this.meetingName,
            meetingUrl: this.meetingSettingUrl,
            meetingPw: this.meetingPW,
            date: this.dates,
            times: this.selectedTime
            }
          )
          this.selectedTime  = [];
        },
    
        generateMeetingLink(){
         let meetinId = this.meetingName
          console.log(this.meetingName)
          this.meetingSettingUrl = "http://localhost:8080/" + meetinId
          this.generatedLink = true
    
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.datesFinal))
    
    
        }
    
      }
```

I just posted the script part as there the logic happens for the array which is generated

Comment: Are the rest of the properties same for all elements in the first array except for `date` and `times` ?

Comment: its like this, one object I am sending has one name, password and url. Then there is one time belonging to the same object, consisting of one date. and multiple start and end times. I hope this was good enough of an explanation

Comment: You can `map()` the array objects and give them the shape you want them to have.

Comment: How do you mean? Maybe you can show me an example this would help me really good. I tried so far setting the fix values like Name in the data section like this datesFinal : [{meetName: this.meetingName}] and then tried pushing the other values but then I get can not read property Push of undefined

Comment: I fixed it I will post my solution as a new answwr

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution I could find:

```
<script>
import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";

export default {
  name: "GenerateMeetingSettings",

  data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],
    finalMeeting: [],
    datesFinal: [{meetingName: "",
      meetingTime: []}] ,
    dates: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10)})
,

  methods:{

    addTimeFields(){
      this.selectedTime.push({
        date: this.dates,
        startTime:"",
        endTime: "",
      })
    },
    saveDateAndTIme(e) {
        this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime.push(this.selectedTime),

          this.selectedTime = []


    },
```